# Flask redirect from outside API functions

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a helper method in a Flask app that is used by several endpoints to get a resource. To avoid having multiple `redirect_url` calls everywhere, I want to be able to redirect from just this helper method. Throwing a `RequestRedirect` exception as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003604/how-to-redirect-from-helper-function-in-flask) correctly returns a `301` response, but doesn't set the `Content-Location` error. To get around this, I added a `after_this_request` hook that sets the url for that response.

This seems to work correctly, but I was wondering if theres a more elegant way to go about it.

Anonymized helper method:

```
def get_resource(resource_id):
    try:
        # Some logic
    except:
        @after_this_request
        def add_header(response):
            response.headers['Content-Location'] = url
            return response
        raise RequestRedirect(new_url='/')
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is outside of your api, typically you would redirect to a 404 page.  Here's a sample:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```